# need to resolve these coding errors, fileReading + seperating data in file

Tags: java, compiler-errors

the task here is to take a file that's filled with 20 lines of data that look roughly like this
Student(name=Jane Robinson,age=19,gpa=3.81) and seperate the three fields name age and gpa, save them to a new object and then fill them in the result array and return that array, but i have run into problems I cannot resolve myself and I need fresh eyes to point out what's wrong with this, I'm running several errors here

```
./StudentReader.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
  for(int i = 0; i < hold1.length(); ++i)
                          ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable hold1 of type String[]
./StudentReader.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    hold2[i] = hold1.split("=");
                    ^
  symbol:   method split(String)
  location: variable hold1 of type String[]
./StudentReader.java:49: error: no suitable method found for add(Scanner)
    result.add(n);
          ^
    method Collection.add(Student) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Scanner cannot be converted to Student)
    method List.add(Student) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Scanner cannot be converted to Student)
    method AbstractCollection.add(Student) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Scanner cannot be converted to Student)
    method AbstractList.add(Student) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Scanner cannot be converted to Student)
    method ArrayList.add(Student) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Scanner cannot be converted to Student)
```

code here:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 * 
 *
 * class StudentReader for retrieveing data from file
 * 
 */
public class StudentReader {
 
  
  public static Student[] readFromTextFile(String fileName) {
   String name =" ";
   int age = 0;
   double gpa = 0.0;
   String fill;
   
    ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<Student>();
    File f = new File(fileName);
    Scanner n = new Scanner(f);
      while (n.hasNextLine()) 
      {
      fill += n.nextLine() +" ";
      }
  n.close();
  
  String[] hold1 = fill.split(",");
  String[] hold2 = new String[hold1.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < hold1.length(); ++i)
   {
     hold2[i] = hold1.split("=");
    if (hold2[i].substring(0,3).equals("name"))
     {
      name = hold2[i].substring(3,hold2[i].length());
     }
    if (hold2[i].substring(0,2).equals("age"))
     {
      age = Integer.parseInt(hold2[i].substring(2,hold2[i].length()));
     }
    if (hold2[i].substring(0,2).equals("gpa"))
     {
      gpa = Double.parseDouble(hold2[i].substring(2,hold2[i].length()));
     }
   
   Student g = new Student(name, age, gpa);
    result.add(n);
  }
    return result.toArray(new Student[0]);
  
}
}
```

for starters i dont even know the cause of the cannot find symbol errors and I cannot even begin to run my tests, as the syntax errors are preventing me here, my debugger tells me nothing so I'm just at a lost here, also if anyone here cant help me where can I go to get help with this?

Comment: Shouldn't you split `hold1[i].split("=")` instead of `hold1.split("=")` ?

Comment: You have several compilation errors there. It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do. Why when reading each line don't you covert it to a `Student` and add it to `result`?

Comment: You use "hold.length" correctly immediately above where you don't.